# Keeping my Navigation at top using fix position

Tags: css, navigation, position, fixed, nav

I am having a problem using fixed positioning with my top navigation bar. I have taken off the code that I have tried and just put it back to normal so maybe someone can see why I am having these problems of formatting when I try to fix the position.

```
#main-header {
/*background:url(images/house.jpg) no-repeat center top;*/
height:734px;
border-bottom:10px solid #162b4b;
}

.epicFullscreen {max-height:735px !important}
.epicFullscreen img {min-height:735px !important}


#top-bar {background: #162b4b; height:60px; margin-top:-98px; margin-bottom:70px}
#top-bar nav {padding-left:260px; padding-top:10px; color:#9297a2; width:75%; float:left}
#top-bar nav a {color:#9297a2; margin-right:30px; text-decoration:none}
#phone {float:right; color:white; padding-top:5px; position:relative; right:90px; top:-15px}
#phone a span {font-size:30px; font-weight:bold; color:#93da04; !important; cursor: default}
#phone > span {font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:#white; !important; cursor: default}
a[href^=tell] {color:inherit}
#logo {
width:233px;
height:98px;
background:white;
position:relative;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
}
#logo img {position:absolute; top:10px; left:30px}
```

When fixing the position, it will take away my top blue bar that sits under the nav text, and fix the nav text to the top and screw up the formatting I have with my phone number (which is a dynamic phone number for split testing purposes with call tracking metrics and analytic's).
I can get it to scroll with the page, but besides the formatting being wrong, while I scroll, it goes underneath some objects and text on the page, not all, while I am scrolling.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, I have read through some of the questions around this issue others have had and the answers are close, but I have not found a solution that works 100% for my website yet.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, I have assumed your main header div contains your navigation bar.

```
#main-header{
    height:734px;
    top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom:10px solid #162b4b;
}
```